# Overloaded Functions:: Which one gets called?

Tags: c++

I have two overloaded functions:

```
void function(int x, int y, int z = 0);
void function(int x, int y)
```

Now, when I call this from main:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;
function(a,b);
```

Which version of `function` will get called?

Comment: Neither. It doesn't compile.

Comment: Did you try this? It won't compile.

Comment: May god, copy much off your homework... at least try to have it make scene. BTW you don't have overloaded functions you don't have anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your code **won't** compile. I'm not sure why you're assigning z a value, but if it were:

```
void function(int x, int y, int z);
void function(int x, int y);
```

and you called

```
function(a,b);
```

The second would be called, assuming you defined the functions.

**Edit: ** An easy way to prove this would be to try and run the code in your compiler. This would let you see the behavior.